# Access to Crashlytics log outside a crash

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Is there a way to access the crashlytics log outside of a crash event?

I was hoping to find something like

```
Crashlytics.instance.currentLog() -> [String]
```

We would like to give our (internal) users a feedback button that sends us email with the user's input and also a copy of the current crashlytics log - so we can see how they got to the point they are asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

You could create a logged error using:

Objective-C:

```
[CrashlyticsKit recordError:error];
```

Swift:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
```

and also record the user's email address with:

Objective-C:

```
[CrashlyticsKit setUserEmail:@"person@domain.com"];
```

Swift:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserEmail("person@domain.com")
```

and then run a search on the user's email address whenever they report this. You would need to cause an error of some kind, but that could get you the data you're looking for.

Documentation on [logged errors](https://firebase.google.com/) and [user identifiers.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822093141/http://docs.fabric.io:80/ios/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#user-identifiers)

Comment: I was hoping for something cleaner.  Since we've wrapped the logging function, we may just add our own log recorder and use that - but I was hoping to just steal yours...
We certainly don't want to have to generate a report and dig for it.
But I do appreciate your timely response!

Comment: Great to know, appreciate the feedback and will share internally.